# using vim regex to prepend/append characters or strings before/after matched strings

Tags: vim, vi

Suppose you have a list like this:

```
file_exts = [tex~, log~, synctex.gz, aux, synctex, tuc, fls, log, fdb_latexmk, bcf, bbl, blg]
```

I want to surround each of the elements with a single quote. Is there a way to do it in Vim efficiently like this?:

```
file_exts = ['tex~', 'log~', 'synctex.gz', 'aux', 'synctex', 'tuc', 'fls', 'log', 'fdb_latexmk', 'bcf', 'bbl', 'blg']
```

The second case is as follows. If I want to append a string to the end of certain lines with strings matched but not replace the strings themselves, how would I do it? Here is an example

```
His name is Evan
His phonenumber is 333-444
```

I want to append say an `...` to the end of the strings matched by `/his`.

```
His name is Evan...
His phonenumber is 333-444...
```

I know I can do this by line number but it is not possible in my use case.

Comment: For the second one, look up the `g/` pattern/line matching in vim

Comment: Similar question here using `\a\+\ze,`. First answer

Comment: @Steve the link is missing.

Comment: Oops here it. https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31756/why-did-a-match-some-non-alphabetic-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question. You may select content inside the `[ ... ]` (e.g. by typing `vi[`) and then execute the following command:

```
:'<,'>s/\%V\([a-z~.]\+\)/'\1'/g
```

Now I am going to explain each part of the command

1. `'<,'>` is a range, it means that we want to apply the following command for selected lines only, not to the whole file. Usually `vim` inserts this automatically when you start command while in visual mode.
2. Similarly `\%V` means here "restrict matching inside the visual area". The range from the `1.` restricts matching only to selected **lines**, but not to selected **characters**. We need `\%V` to prevent applying the command to the `file_exts` word.
3. `s/pattern/replacement/` is just a substitusion command: it replaces the specified `pattern` with the specified `replacement`.
4. `[a-z~.]\+` is just a regular expression, which means "match a sequence of one or more characters from the list: `a`-`z`, `~` or `.`".
5. We do not want to substitute, but modify existing items. So in the pattern part we save it with the `\( ... )` construction to a (somewhat) register, and use it later as `\1` in the replacement part. So the replacement part is just `'\1'`.
6. By default `vim` applies substitution only once per line. We want to apply it multiple times, so we added the `g` flag at the end of the command.

This is not the easiest way possible, but fairly straightforward and easily customizable for similar tasks.

If you want more details for each of the topics, you may check out vim help:

```
:help '<
:help '>
:help \%V
:help pattern
:help :s
:help s/\1
:help s_flags
```

For the second question: besides the `g/` solution mentioned in the comments, you may use `:s` as well:

```
:'<,'>s/\(Evan\|444\)$/\1...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve the first one without using a visual selection is the following regex:

```
:%s/\([a-z~.]\+\)\([,\]]\)/'\1'\2/g
```

It makes use of the fact, that there is always a `,` or a `]` in the end of the word. It does match two groups

1. the word you want to enclose
2. the end of the word (`,` or `]`)

It then replaces the first group with a enclosed version and does add the second group back to the end.

Comment: very useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### First question

Here is a bit of lateral thinking:

```
ci[
<C-r>=split(@", ', ')->map({ idx, val -> "'" . val . "'" })->join(', ')
```

where… the content of the brackets is split, then quoted, then put together again.

See `:help c_ctrl-r`, `:help "=`, `:help split()`, `:help map()`, `:help lambda`, and `:help join()`.

### Second question

Use `:help :global` and `:help :normal` for that:

```
:g/^His/normal! A...<CR>
```

where…

- `:g/<pattern>/<command>` executes `<command>` on each line matching `<pattern>`,
- `:normal <macro>` executes normal mode `<macro>` starting from the current line.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the First Question -

`:%s/, /', '/g`

Then manually add ' after [ and before ]